# Guaranteed way to compare objects by identity in Ruby

Tags: ruby, compare

What is a guaranteed way to compare two objects by their identity in Ruby?  Given two variables, I want to return true if the variables point to the exact same object in memory.

For most Ruby objects, the `equal?` method compares by identity:

```
f = g = Object.new
p f.equal? g  # => true
```

However, this doesn't work for all objects.  For example:

```
class F
  def ==(obj) false end
  def ===(obj) false end
  def eql?(obj) false end
  def equal?(obj) false end
  def object_id; self end
end

f = g = F.new
p f == g       # => false
p f === g      # => false
p f.eql? g     # => false
p f.equal? g   # => false
p f.object_id == g.object_id  # => false
```

What is a foolproof/guaranteed way of comparing two objects by identity which can't be defeated?

This is a purely intellectual question.  The answer to any question that begins with "why" will probably be "Because I am curious."

Comment: What's the word for things in computer science and math like F?  There is some word for it.  I want to say "diabolical", but less evil.

Comment: I think the word is "wrong." As in, it is not a thing you should do.

Comment: I want to use a word that begins with "F"... There are no guarantees unless you want to write a C extension, you're supposed to be polite but there's nothing stopping anyone from being an anti-social sociopath.

Comment: You'd be able to tell that something was amiss by the fact that `object_id` wasn't an integer.

Comment: @Andrew: But the there's always `def object_id; 11 end`.

Comment: @muistooshort in that case I'd see if doing id2ref of the object id gives me the same object as the original. Or see if the object equals itself.

Comment: @Andrew: `def object_id; rand(10000) end`. And how do you rely on "see if the object equals itself" when faced with a pathological case like `F`? The real underlying problem is that we don't know how to ask **Ruby** if two objects are equal, we can only ask **the objects** if they're equal; if we can't trust the objects to behave then what do we do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could grab an unbound version of [`Object#object_id`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-object_id), bind it to the object in question, and see what it says. Given your `F` class with one addition:

```
class F
  # ...
  def inspect; 'pancakes!' end # Just so we can tell what we have later.
end
```

Then:

```
>> f = F.new
>> f.object_id
=> pancakes!
>> unbound_object_id = Object.instance_method(:object_id)
>> unbound_object_id.bind(f).call
=> 2153000340
>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(2153000340).inspect
=> "pancakes!"
```

Of course, if someone opens up Object and replaces `object_id` then you're out of luck but this will be the least of your problems if someone does that. If you can grab your `unbound_object_id` [UnboundMethod](https://ruby-doc.org/core/UnboundMethod.html) before anything else is loaded, then it won't matter if someone changes `Object#object_id` as your `unbound_object_id` will still be the original correct one.

So this round-about hack gives you a reliable `object_id` for any object (subject to the caveats above). Now you can grab and compare the object ids to get your reliable comparison.

Comment: Great, it works!  I'd just like to contribute a function that uses this technique to compare two variables by identity: `def compare_by_identity(x, y); id = Object.instance_method :object_id; id.bind(x).call == id.bind(y).call; end`

Answer (score 9):

Use `BasicObject#equal?`.  According to [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F):

> Unlike ==, the equal? method should never be overridden by subclasses: it is used to determine object identity (that is, a.equal?(b) iff a is the same object as b).

Need stronger guarantee?  AFAIK can't receive it, `BaseObject#object_id`, `ObjectSpace._id2ref`, `Hash#compare_by_identity` can be overriden or monkey patched too (at least this is my personal belief).

Comment: You can provide your own `def equal?(other) false end` implementation if you have a sufficiently hateful attitude.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by *mu is too short* is great, but there is another way you can do it using a special feature of the Hash class:

```
def compare_by_identity(x, y)
  h = {}.compare_by_identity
  h[x] = 1
  h[y] = 2
  h.keys.size == 1
end
```

The `compare_by_identity` feature was added in Ruby 1.9.2, so this function won't work in earlier versions.  I think *mu is too short*'s answer is better.